# Is there a more elegant way to remove Nones from list after list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm using a list comprehension to map a function that either returns a value or None.

My function looks like this (this is extremely simplified, just to give you a general idea)

```
def convertline(x):
    if x == 'undesirablevalue':
        return None
    else:
        # do some logic
        # do some logic
        # do some logic
        return somecalculatedvalue
```

and I have it iterating over a list in a list comprehension, like so. To filter out the nones, I use a list comprehension.

```
items = [convertline(line) for line in sample2.splitlines()]
items = [x for x in items if x is not None]
```

But the above code seems bulky.
I realized I could also do this:

```
items = [convertline(line) for line in sample2.splitlines() if convertline(line) is not None]
```

But this seems garbled, and I also do the math twice. Is there a better, more elegant way to do this? Both solutions seem kind of bulky. Thanks

Comment: @HarunYilmaz And both get a NameError for sample2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's really nothing wrong with your original approach. I would greatly prefer it over the approach that calls the function twice, that seems definitely wasteful, especially if it does a lot of work.

If you are using >=Python3.8, you can use an assignment expression:

```
[result for x in data if (result:= foo(x)) is not None]
```

Alternatively, the following which uses `map`, only does a single pass and doesn't build an intermediate list:

```
[x for x in map(foo, data) if x is not None]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could it the other way around:

```py
def convertline(x):
    # do some logic
    # do some logic
    # do some logic
    return somecalculatedvalue

items = [convertline(line) for line in sample2.splitlines() if line is not 'undesirablevalue']
```

A function that returns `None` is a bit weird in my opinion.

Comment: That just addresses their "extremely simplified" example.